# Insert 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to DateTime in Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Is there a way to insert **"0000-00-00 00:00:00"** to send from **PHP to store it in MySql database** ?

Should I change the database field's default value as **"0000-00-00 00:00:00"** ?

Comment: *Should I change the database field's default value as "0000-00-00 00:00:00"* **Depends on your requirements, generally, answer is NO**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont pass any argument to your `DateTime` column.

```
 insert into table_name (column_name) values('');
```

For update

```
 update table_name set column_name='' where other_column_name=value
```

Comment: It is throwing me an error that null value has been passed, while writing the update query.

Comment: Actually, I want to update the column with the latest values entered by the user, So this INSERT query may not work, right?

Comment: Yes, the updated answer is correct. Thank you. But, I need to post this in Drupal queries as I'm getting error in my Drupal site while writing my custom module.